# whenever I run ng serve I encounter problem

Tags: javascript, angular, components, compiler-warnings

This issue is persisting

```
X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:2:2:
      2 │   <app-header></app-header>
        ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-firsts' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-firsts' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-firsts' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:3:2:
      3 │   <app-firsts></app-firsts>
        ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-matches' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-matches' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-matches' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:4:2:
      4 │   <app-matches></app-matches>
        ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-aboutus' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-aboutus' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-aboutus' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:5:2:
      5 │   <app-aboutus></app-aboutus>
        ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-privacypolicy' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-privacypolicy' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-privacypolicy' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:6:2:
      6 │   <app-privacypolicy></app-privacypolicy>
        ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-successstory' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-successstory' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-successstory' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:7:2:
      7 │   <app-successstory></app-successstory>
        ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-loginpage' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-loginpage' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-loginpage' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress 
this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:8:2:
      8 │   <app-loginpage></app-loginpage>
        ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-plan' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-plan' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-plan' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this 
message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:9:2:
      9 │   <app-plan></app-plan>
        ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress 
this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:10:2:
      10 │   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
         ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
      5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

here is my [app.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZtM7.png)[here is my header.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRRdJ.png) the selectors are correct I checked but issue persists. declarations and import in appmodule is also correct, dont know why issue persists.

the selectors are correct I checked but issue persists. declarations and import in app module is also correct and app-routing.module.ts is also right dont know what is problem

Comment: _add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas'_ Have you tried this suggestion?

Comment: It looks like you are missing imports for the module.
Are the components part of the same module? And if not, do you import the given module(s) and do you export these componentes from those modules?